# Number of odd cycles in non-bipartite 3-connected graph

Tags: graph-theory

By going over the tests of previous years in graph theory, I've come across an interesting (in my opinion) question:

$G$ is 3-connected, non-bipartite graph. Prove that $G$ contains at least 4 odd cycles.

I tried the following way: as $G$ is non-bipartite, it has an odd cycle $C$. Now, since $G$ 3-connected, there should be $v \in V(G-C)$ with 3 paths to $C$. From here it should be a game of combining odd/even paths, to get what is needed. But there are too much options.

Is there any other way?

Thanks.

Comment: @Graphth: Given the statement that Pavel wants to prove, it seems likely that *bipartite* in the third paragraph is a typo for *non-bipartite*.

Comment: Sorry, indeed. Fixed.

Comment: @Pavel I assume you admite any 4 odd cycles, because if you want they to be independent, then the 3-regular graph of 4 vertices would not satisfy the claim.

Comment: @iago Yes, I think that was the intention.

Comment: @Pavel Following your idea, you can reduce the combinations of the paths to only 3 options (not too much). Decomposing the cycle in 3 odd-lenght paths you may assume that it has lenght 3 (the important is just parity). Now take $v$ at distance 1 of a vertex of the cycle. Then the only combinations you have to consider if the 2 paths to the other vertices of the cycle are odd-odd, even-even or even-odd.

Comment: @iago I think there is more to that. I'm not sure how you can decompose the cycle, before you know where the paths from $v$ will go. The decomposition, as I see it, is made by them. And then, you'll need to take the parities of this decomposition into account too.

Comment: @Pavel It has to be paths in $G-C$ from $v$ to each vertex of the cycle because otherwise the graph wouldn't be 3-connected (since removing the 2 vertices in the cycle next to one without path to $v$, the graph would get disconnected). Then you can decompose the cycle as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is correct and doesn't have that many cases, you can simplify it quite a bit. Let $C$ be an odd cycle in $G$ of minimum length, this assures that $C$ isn't hamiltonian and there is a vertex $v\in V(G)\setminus V(C)$. As you said, there are 3 disjoint paths $t_1$, $t_2$ and $t_3$ between $v$ and $C$. Call $x_i$ the extreme of $t_i$ in $C$. Observe that for $i\neq j$, there are two $x_ix_j$-paths contained in $C$, one of even length and one of odd length. Define the cycle $C_{i,j}$ as follows:

1. If the sum of the lengths of $t_i$ and $t_j$ is even, the cycle starts in $v$, follows $t_i$, then the odd $x_ix_j$-path in $C$ and finally it follows $t_j$.
2. If the sum of the lengths of $t_i$ and $t_j$ is odd, do the same but use the even $x_ix_j$-path in $C$.

Hence, the four odd cycles are $C$, $C_{1,2}$, $C_{1,3}$ and $C_{2,3}$.